# How do I pass parameters to NuGet in a Visual Studio Online Build definition?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution with multiple projects in it checked in to TFS (Visual Studio Team Services). I only want one of those projects (and therefore its dependencies) to build and deploy to an Azure Web Site I have created. My solution and its projects follow the NuGet 2.7+ Automatic Package Restore method according to [this guide](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore). Everything works as expected in my local Visual Studio 2013 environment.

I created a very basic deployment build in Team Services using [this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/06/12/deploying-an-azure-web-site-using-the-new-build-system-in-visual-studio-online.aspx), but the build fails with this error regarding NuGet:

```
******************************************************************************
Running tasks
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Build solution $/Path/To/My/Project.csproj
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.16\VSBuild.ps1
C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\a\1\s\Path\To\My\Project.csproj" -NonInteractive
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.
Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
```

My question is: how exactly do I `specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory`? I wasn't able to find any documentation regarding this.

Or, perhaps I am going about this in the wrong way altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you seem to use an outdated approach for NuGet Package restore (with `.nuget` folder in version control). See [this blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html) for a writing about the limitations of this approach.

If you need to pass specific arguments to `nuget.exe` for package restoring you should use the separate "NuGet Installer" task, which has a "NuGet Arguments" parameter where you can provide further option to the `nuget.exe restore` command.

If you use the "NuGet Installer" task for package restore you can disable the "Restore NuGet Packages" option in the "Visual Studio Build" task.